Backups failing for VM running SQL database for Windows Server 2019 RDS License Service
We have a Windows Server 2019 VM's failing backup using Unitrends.
After investigation, we  found it is not a Unitrends issue, but an issue in the Guest  preventing checkpoints from being created successfully.
On the host, the event log shows:

'servername' could not initiate a checkpoint operation: Catastrophic failure (0x8000FFFF). (Virtual machine ID 11ACC7DC-8FF9-40E8-8BD2-7075BF5D7439)

In the Guest OS, I can see the error:

The selected writer SqlServerWriter is in a failed state, status 12,
The operation completed successfully.

Stopping the "Windows Internal Database" SQL Server database service in the VM enables checkpoints to be created successfully, so I know I have identified the service that is causing the issue, but I am  struggling to find anything useful in the event logs or log files that can help identify the cause of the error.

That is definitely a failure with the agent.

You need to go through the check list for configuring the SQL agent.  https://guides.unitrends.com/documents/rs-ueb-admin-guide/Content/Satori/SQL_backup_requirements_and_considerations.htm
